# Using NAudio with SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, naudio

I would like to use NAudio together with SpeechSynthesizer, but I cannot make it work without writing a .wav file to disk first.

I cannot figure out why, I tried both RAW wave data and wave with headers, see the following examples...

**Example 1 - this works, but saves a .wav file**

```
  using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
  {
    synth.SetOutputToWaveFile(@".\Test.wav");
    synth.Speak("This is sample text-to-speech output.");
    synth.SetOutputToNull();

    var reader = new WaveFileReader(@".\Test.wav");
    var waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(reader);
    waveOut.Play();
  }
```

**Example 2 - this also works, but still uses a file**

```
  using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);
    synth.Speak("This is sample text-to-speech output.");

    using (var fileStream = File.Create(@".\Test.wav"))
    {
      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }

    var reader = new WaveFileReader(@".\Test.wav");
    var waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(reader);
    waveOut.Play();
  }
```

**Example 3 - this don´t work, it just play a fraction of a second and stops**

It´s on purpose that I use SetOutputToWaveStream to keep the RIFF header, to avoid setting wave format.

```
    using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);
      synth.Speak("This is sample text-to-speech output.");

      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      var reader = new WaveFileReader(stream);
      var waveOut = new WaveOut();
      waveOut.Init(reader);
      waveOut.Play();
    }
```

**Example 4 - same result as example 3**

This uses raw data and is a bit bulky.

```
  using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    synth.SetOutputToAudioStream(stream, new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono));
    synth.Speak("This is sample text-to-speech output.");

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1));
    var waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(provider);
    waveOut.Play();
  }
```

I also tried using WasapiOut, but that was even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just about there with Example 3. Call `Flush` on your memory stream before repositioning to the start. Also, `Play` only starts playing, so you need to either wait for playback to finish or move your `WaveOut` instance to be outside the `using` block. Otherwise it's just going to get garbage collected before it can get very far into playback.

Comment: Thank you, was starring myself blind on it, It was off cause because the garbage collection. I thought that Flush() on a memory stream was redundant since it´s already written directly to RAM ??.

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.memorystream.flush(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: yeah probably the flush isn't necessary, it's just what I have in my own implementation so I thought I'd mention it anyway

Comment: I also had to put the SpeechSynthesizer in its own thread, otherwise I would still have the problem only getting a fragment of the output. See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5599972/3131828) for more information.

Comment: no need for another thread, just wait until playback is finished. You're disposing the player too early.

Answer (score 1):

this code works for me, if can help (for solution 3).

```
        IWaveProvider provider = null;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {

            synth.SetOutputToAudioStream(stream,
                new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono));
            synth.Speak("This is sample text-to-speech output.");

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1));

        }
        var waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(provider);
        waveOut.Play();
```